# Как сделать случайный выбор сцен в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При прохождении уровня игрока должно перекидывать на следующий (Случайно выбирает одну из сцен).Также нужно что бы некоторые сцены могли попадаться уже на поздних стадиях (После 40 побед).

Comment: А вы сами что-то пробовали сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle;
private string[] scenePaths;
private Random r = new random;

void Start()
{
    //находим папку с сценами
    myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile("Assets/AssetBundles/scenes");
    // запоминаем пути к каждой сцене
    scenePaths = myLoadedAssetBundle.GetAllScenePaths();
}

void OnGUI()
{
    // кнопочка для открытия сцены
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), "Change Scene"))
    {
        // ищем любую сцену с переменной scenePaths
        var sceneNumber = r.Next(0,scenePaths.length - 1);
        // отображаем в консоли путь к сцене
        Debug.Log("Scene loading: " + scenePaths[sceneNumber]);
        // открываем сцену
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scenePaths[sceneNumber], LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) все это есть. Ну и сам [случайный выбор(Random)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Сам метод я понял , но я имел введу что сцены будут "отрываться" без воли игрока.      Например: после прохождения мини-уровня игрока кидает сразу же на следующий(Первые 40 побед он может перекидываться только на первые 50 сцен , после же в рандом попадают сцена из всего списка).

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Делайте `LoadScene` например после прохождения мини уровня....у вас же есть логика на проверку пройден уровень или нет...вот при условии если он пройден и вызывайте.

Comment: Проблемы нет.                                                                              
Просто решил добавить комментарий по этому поводу.

Comment: Просто решил немного другим способом:                                                                                                     Сцены вызываются по индексу(рандомному).После прохождения уровня происходит int q +=1.Если int >40 то диапазон рандома увеличивается .                                                              Ваш ответ мне помог но через пару часов пришел в голову этот способ,который показался мне легче.