# Отдельные группы сцен для загрузки Unity

Tags: unity3d

Как правильно спроектировать сцены в проекте Unity?
Я хочу сделать несколько Групп сцен (кампании в игре).

> Сейчас я могу все сцены засунуть в build settings. Сохранить
>   пройденные уровни например цифра - 5. И при следующем открытии игры
>   загрузить цифру - 5.  Значит пройдено 5 уровней (индекс уровня 4 так
>   как индекс с нуля),  загрузить последнюю сцену по индексу - 4
>
> А если делать компании то игрок может выбрать первую компанию пройти 5 уровней (индекс сцены 4) -
>   СОХРАНИЛИ цифру 5
>   потом выбрать вторую компанию пройти 1 уровень (индекс сцены допустим 60)
>   СОХРАНИЛИ?

Как правильно хранить сцены или придётся делать сложную систему сохранения?
Я ничего не могу найти в интернете... Видимо это что-то элементарное...
Я всё понятно объяснил?
**БОЛЬШАЯ ПЕЧЕНЬКА ЗА ТО ЧТО ДОЧИТАЛИ! :)**

Comment: В чем проблема сохранить 2 цифры?

Comment: В том что если я захочу добавить уровней к первой компании, индекс второй компании сместиться.

Comment: @polygon Используй имена а не индексы. а в имени делай что то типо 1_4 2_16

Comment: @polygon каким образом это произойдет, если будет 2 разных числа для 2х разных кампаний?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так как сохранение у меня происходит в числах которые соответствуют индексу в build settings. Первая компания занимает индексы 0-60 а вторая 61-70. Если я сохраню 2 числа индексов. (соответствующих каждой компании). всё будет хорошо.
Но при следующем обновлении я допустим добавлю уровней первой компании индекс последней пройденной сцены сместиться допустим вверх. Сохранённый индекс для второй компании тоже будет неверным. Так как он останется прежним а последняя сцена пройденная во второй компании будет выше...

Comment: @Don Antonio Gollum видимо придётся както шифровать компанию в названии и получать доступ к сцене по имени. Но это тоже неудобно конечно.. Тоесть название сцены например:
Com1_0_NameScene; Com1_1_NameScene; Com2_0_NameScene; Но тогда для получения имени сцены в меню придётся убирать все символы до второго процерка "_".
Это тоже неудобные костыли... 
Как это сделать более элегантно?

Comment: кажется я нашёл как разделить сцены из разных компаний в разные папки. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972030/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2-unity?rq=1